# Spring 3.5 how to add HttpSessionEventPublisher to my boot configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to listen to session life cycle events. I read about adding

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>
     org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

to web.xml. But I don't have it. I am using class that extends SpringBootServletInitializer. How I can add this listener?

Answer (score 18):

You can use `ServletListenerRegistrationBean`:

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

Comment: I have add this code to my SpringBootServletInitializer class. But my problem still exists. When user login and then logout and try to login once again it get an error about incorrect user\pass.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide reference to official documentation,
http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#httpsession-rest

Here if you refer to, `HttpSessionListener` topic, you will find the clear example of doing it both `Java` and `XML` configuration way.

if your configuration support `Redis`

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisHttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    // ...
}
```

In XML configuration, this might look like

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Listener in Class which is extending SpringBootSelvletInitializer can be done as below.

```
    @Configuration
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder app=application.sources(Application.class, ComponentConfiguration.class);
    app.listeners(bootstrapContext.commandLineListener());
    return app;
}
```

As the builder class is having listener method which use to add all the listener which is given to be registered. Github link for SpringApplicationBuilder is http://goo.gl/EGj6jE

I think this will solve your issue.

Swaraj

Answer (score 0):

From `SpringBootServletInitializer` javadoc : *A handy opinionated WebApplicationInitializer for applications that only have one Spring servlet, and no more than a single filter (which itself is only enabled when Spring Security is detected). If your application is more complicated consider using one of the other WebApplicationInitializers*

So if you want to generate a war and you want to include a session listener, you should use directly a `WebApplicationInitializer`. Here is an example from the javadoc :

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

As you have full control on the ServletContext before it is fully initialized, it is easy to add your listener :

```
    container.addListener(YourListener.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use HttpSessionEventPublisher:

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

like in this description: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session